# NOT IN for LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is there a way for me to filter Employees by group:
ex:

```
List<String> notInGroups = GetNotInGroups();

    var list = from p in employees 
    where p.Group.Name notin(notInGroups)
    select p;
```

Is there some way to do something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, normally I'd use `Where(p => !notInGroups.Contains(p.Group.Name))` (not sure on the SQL-like syntax for that), though I'd seriously consider using a `HashSet<string>` rather than `List<string>` for the fast lookup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do !Contains, like:

```
var list = from p in employees
where !notInGroups.Contains(p.Group.Name)
select p;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not able to test, but won't something like this work?

```
var notInGroups = GetNotInGroups();
var list = from p in employees 
           where notInGroups.Contains(p.Group.Name) == false
           select p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `where !notInGroups.Contains(p.Group.Name);` as your `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this..

```
List<String> notInGroups = GetNotInGroups();

var list = from p in employees 
           where !(notInGroups.Contains(p.Group.Name))
           select p;
```

Comment: Edited: you forgot a closing-brace at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is not particularly well suited for the task of searching through the collection to see if it contains a particular item, which is exactly what you want to do.  While writing the code is easy enough (there are already a lot of answers showing how) you will benefit noticeably from using a more appropriate data structure that can be more efficiently searched, such as a `HashSet`:

```
var notInGroups = new HashSet<string>(GetNotInGroups());

var list = from p in employees 
    where !notInGroups.Contains(p.Group.Name)
    select p;
```